# I don't understand why I am getting a syntax error or how to fix it

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

const double cm_per_inch = 2.54;
const double lb_per_kg = 2.20462262;

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int lucky,m,d,y;
    double h_in,w_lb,h_cm,w_kg;
cout << "Zelda's Lucky Number Calculator" << endl 
    << "Enter the month of your birthday in numerical form:" ;
cin >> m;
cout << "Enter the date of your birthday:" ;
cin >> d;
cout << "Enter the year of your birthday:" ;
cin >> y;
cout << "Enter your height in inches:" ;
cin >> h_in;
cout << "Enter your weight in pounds:" ;
cin >> w_lb;
//Convert height into cm and weight into kg
h_cm = h_in*cm_per_inch;
w_kg = w_lb/lb_per_kg;
//Calculate lucky number
lucky = static_cast<int>(((static_cast<double>(m) 100*pow(m,2) + 10*pow(d,3))/y+      (sqrt(pow(w_kg,6)/h_cm))))  % 10 + 1;
//Display lucky number
cout << "Your lucky number is " <<lucky<< ". Thank you, that will be $25." << endl ;
return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> c:\users\fields\desktop\school\cse 100\lab3\soumishyrkas_lab3.cpp(35): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
>   c:\users\fields\desktop\school\cse 100\lab3\soumishyrkas_lab3.cpp(35): error C2143: syntax error : missing '(' before 'constant'
>   c:\users\fields\desktop\school\cse 100\lab3\soumishyrkas_lab3.cpp(35): error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Answer (score 7):

`static_cast<double>(m) 100`

You're missing an operator of some sort here. You can't just have a `static_cast` next to an integer litteral. I don't know what your exact formula is but I'm assuming there should be a `+` there.

Comment: Yes I think a `+` clearly fits in there. +1